# hyphenation character in xslt attribute (xsl-fo)

Tags: xslt, attributes, special-characters, xsl-fo

I think it's a very simple question. But although I build very fancy xslt transformation, this simple one cannot be solved by me.

The problem is:
I want to add attributes to xsl-fo nodes, depending on xml data. These attributes have often a hyphen in it. How can I add these with an xslt transformation where xsl:attributes doesn't like the hyphenation character.

---

In a xml node I have got two attributes (name and value)
   Example: name="font_size", value="7pt"

```
<Report>
  <text content="I am a text">
    <blockFormat name="font_size" value="7pt" />
  </text>
</Report>
```

(I understand this is not wanted because you want to work with styles etceters. It's just an example with a simplified problem)

---

Now I want to make a xsl-fo block, and I want to place that attributes in the block element by using the xsl-function xsl:attribute

```
<fo:block>
  <attribute name="{replace(@name,'_','-')}" select="@value" />
....
</fo:block>
```

---

goal to achieve after transformation

```
<fo:block font-size="7pt">
....
</fo:block
```

It doesn't function and I think this is because in xslt I can't put an hyphen in the attribute name, but in the fo-attribute it is needed.

Is there a way to use the xsl:attribute function for this?

And when not, what kind of working around do you suggest.

Thank you for helping!!!!

Comment: "*I think this is because in xslt I can't put an hyphen in the attribute name*" Sure you can. How exactly is this failing? Do you get an error message? And are you sure you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 1000 ways to do it, here is one (I didn't do anything with your Report element):

Input:

```
<Report>
    <text content="I am a text">
        <blockFormat name="font_size" value="7pt" />
    </text>
</Report>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="Report">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="blockFormat/@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@content"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@name">
        <xsl:attribute name="{translate(.,'_','-')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::blockFormat/@value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@value"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Report>
   <fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-size="7pt">I am a text</fo:block>
</Report>
```

Comment: Fantastic and indeed too simple for words. I didn't use the function translate and that caused me trouble. Now I can handle it easilly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `@select` instead of `@value`:

```
<fo:block>
  <attribute name="{replace(@name,'_','-')}" select="@value" />
....
</fo:block>
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-attributes

Also, you need to be using XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 to use `@select`.  If you're using XSLT 1.0, you'd have to do it as `xsl:attribute/xsl:value-of/@select`.

(It would also have helped understanding of your problem if you'd also shown the wrong result that you were getting.)

Comment: Excuse me, i made a mistake when typing the question. I use 'select'. You couldn't know. The problem is that I don't get a wrong output, but a failure when transforming. Maybe it's only in the xsl-fo processing-step. I can't see that very quickly. I'll try to find out.

Comment: `<attribute` should be `<xsl:attribute` (unless that's also a typo?).  If that's not the problem, what are you producing as the `fo:block` start-tag?